# Missing links in new camera stack wiki pages

Tags: ros, stack, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently created several new camera driver stacks:

- [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394)
- [prosilica_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/prosilica_driver)
- [wge100_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wge100_driver)

While working on their documentation pages in the ROS wiki, I have been unable to get the "ChangeList" and "Releases" links to display, despite the fact that those sub-pages actually exist.

Also, the "Dependencies" and "Used by" links on the [camera1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) page show up, but do nothing when clicked.

Is some additional documentation index update required for these new stacks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12633/missing-links-in-new-camera-stack-wiki-pages/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-01-16**:
I'll look into it .. i filed a ticket here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3813

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-12**:
The "ChangeList" and "Releases" problems seem to have been fixed as a side-effect of some other change. A workaround for the "Dependencies" problem is described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticketed at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3813

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-12**:
The "Dependencies" and "Used by" problem was caused by a bad interaction between the `Version()` and `StackHeader()` macros, fixed by moving the `StackHeader()` outside the `Version()` scope.